# "Hasn't it occurred to you"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> A: You can't help me, so why are you still trying so hard?
>
> B: Hasn't it occurred to you that I might be trying this hard because I actually do think I know how you feel?

Is "hasn't it occurred to you" closest in meaning to "haven't you realized" or "hasn't it crossed your mind" or somewhere in between?

Comment: For your context, I'd say there's no significant difference between "haven't you realized" and "hasn't it crossed your mind", so it's meaningless to ask whether "Hasn't it occurred to you" is closer to one than to the other. Can you explain in more detail exactly what "difference" you think *might* be involved, so we can more precisely explain why you are mistaken about the possibility of any such difference?

Comment: (In some *other* contexts, you normally only "realise" things which are assumed to be ***true***, whereas things that "cross your mind" might simply be ***possibilities*** which turn out not to be true anyway.)

Comment: In my example B has given no clues to A, so it's not likely that A would know. So I feel that it would be weird expecting A to know, which I think "haven't you realized" indicates?

Comment: I think you're over-thinking things here. Obviously people often say things like *Don't you realise I'm joking?* when it's blindingly obvious there's ***no chance at all*** that the addressee is aware of / realises that "truth". But to the extent there's any difference between the two ways of asking, it's to do with whether or not the thing being asked about is definitely true or just a possibility - it doesn't really make any difference how likely it is that the addressee should be aware of the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Would all the three suggestions be natural to use in the context?

Comment: In your *exact* context I wouldn't use *any* of these alternatives. They all strike me as incredibly rude - which in other contexts might be intentional *(Hasn't [some obvious thing] occurred to you? If not, you must be an idiot!)*, but it's not a good fit when the "truth" being asserted is "I know how you feel" (which implies being sympathetic, rather than insulting).

Comment: "occured" in this context means "come into the mind of". This is a standard dictionary definition, so voting to close.

Comment: @Astralbee - OP didn't ask about "come into the mind of", and dictionary definitions are only good for telling us "literal" meanings - denotations.  This question is more connotative in nature.  It's a fine question and should not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

> Haven't you realized that I might be trying this hard because I actually do think I know how you feel?

> Hasn't it crossed your mind that I might be trying this hard because I actually do think I know how you feel?

^ These two are very similar, but actually slightly different.

The first, using "realized", is asking if the listener knows with certainty that the speaker "might be trying ...."

"Realizations" connote knowledge that happened "all at once" and strikes us as definitely true, immediately.  The speaker strongly expected that the listener would have previously "realized".

The second, using "crossed your mind", is asking if the listener has considered the possibility that the speaker "might be trying ...."

"Crossing the mind" is something that happens "at leisure", and connote knowledge that is "being considered".

In context both of them imply that the speaker is /in fact/ "trying this hard because...."

> "Hasn't it occurred to you..."

^ This is somewhere in-between the two!  An "occurrence" of thought is sudden, but not a "flash of realization" and not certainly true.  The listener might say "It had occurred to me, yes", and might still mean he was uncertain.

All three are natural.